# ExecutorService interface execute method using Executors class in java

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, java.util.concurrent, executor

Please don't close this question. It is not related to question [What does it mean to "program to an interface"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface)

I am trying to learn ExecutorService interface and its methods. I created an object of type ExecutorService using Executors class static method newFixedThreadPool() and trying to call the execute() method of ExecutorService interface.

```java
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

class WorkerThread implements Runnable {
    private String message;

    public WorkerThread(String s) {
        this.message = s;
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " (Start) message = " + message);

        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " (End)");// prints thread name
    }

}

public class TestThreadPool {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);// creating a pool of 5 threads
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Runnable worker = new WorkerThread("" + i);
            executor.execute(worker);// calling execute method of ExecutorService
        }
        
        executor.shutdown();
        while (!executor.isTerminated()) {
        }

        System.out.println("Finished all threads");
    }
}
```

In above code, I have created an object of type ExecutorService using Executors class newFixedThreadPool method which creates a pool of 5 threads.

But How executor is calling execute() method here, as it is an abstract method of ExecutorService interface and the Executors class also don't have any execute() method?

Comment: Hi @RenéLink, I think you have not read my question completely. There is no execute() method in Executors class. You can check in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html also. So, how execute() method is implemented here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But How executor is calling execute() method here, as it is an abstract method of ExecutorService interface and the Executors class also don't have any execute() method?

`Executors.newFixedThreadPool` returns an instance of a class that implements `ExecutorService`. This instance has the `execute` method.

See [`Executors.newFixedThreadPool(int)`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/739769c8fc4b496f08a92225a12d07414537b6c0/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/Executors.java#L91)

```
public static ExecutorService newFixedThreadPool(int nThreads) {
    return new ThreadPoolExecutor(nThreads, nThreads,
                                  0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                                  new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
}
```

The `ThreadPoolExecutor` implments the `execute` method. See [`ThreadPoolExecutor.java#L1327`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/739769c8fc4b496f08a92225a12d07414537b6c0/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.java#L1327). The `ThreadPoolExecutor` extends [`AbstractExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/AbstractExecutorService.html) and the `AbstractExecutorService` implements `Executor` and `ExecutorService`.

[image: AbstractExecutorService Javadoc]

**EDIT**

> Hi, could you also share the link of Executors class all method?

Here is the [`Executors` source](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/739769c8fc4b496f08a92225a12d07414537b6c0/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/Executors.java)

Comment: Hi, could you also share the link of Executors class all method?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed there is no method Execute in Executors class. It's a method in the ExecutorService class. You are calling exactly this method. In fact it's a method of the Executor interface, which ExecutorService class implements: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html#execute(java.lang.Runnable)

Look at the section "All superinterfaces" in the documentation you pasted: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html